# Script with nested for loops

Tags: linux, terminal, for

This is the code and I need to display in the terminal like this way:

```
(1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (1,5)
(2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4) (2,5)
(3,1) (3,2) (3,3) (3,4) (3,5)
(4,1) (4,2) (4,3) (4,4) (4,5)
```

but my output it's like this:

```
1,1) 1,1) 1,1) 1,1) 1,1)  
2,1) 2,1) 2,1) 2,1) 2,1)  
3,1) 3,1) 3,1) 3,1) 3,1)  
4,1) 4,1) 4,1) 4,1) 4,1)
```

I don't know where I had make the mistake. I am sorry if the mistake is obvious.

```
        for (( i = 1; i < 5; i++ ))
        do

        for (( j=1; j<=5; j++))
        do
        echo -n "$i,1) " 

        done

        echo " "
        done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$j` variable was unused:

```
for (( i=1; i<5; i++ )); do
  for (( j=1; j<=5; j++)); do
    echo -n "($i,$j) "
  done
  echo
done
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your `echo` line. You're missing the open paren and you're not printing the value of `$j`. Try:

```
echo -n "($i,$j) "
```

You may need to escape the parens, I'm not sure off the top of my head.